# Connection partially unavailable if connected to modem but works when connected to router

Tags: router, networking, modem

Trying to get a mystery solved. I am connected thru ethernet cable. Some URLs stop working when the cable is plugged into the modem directly.

For example I can access portal.azure.com but management.azure.com doesnt work

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://portal.azure.com
StatusCode        : 200

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://management.azure.com
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

ping management.azure.com                                                                                
Pinging arm-0001.arm-msedge.net [4.150.240.10] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 4.150.240.10: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=110
Reply from 4.150.240.10: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=110
Reply from 4.150.240.10: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=110
Reply from 4.150.240.10: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=110
```

Ping works fine but some how the https get request fails. I tried switching DNS, flush dns, accessing using a VM. None of them worked.

Everything starts working once I plug the cable to the router. But the router is plugged into the modem at the end of the day too. My only theory would be that TCP connection to management.azure.com fails while UDP succeed. Still very curious to find out what could contribute to this strange behavior.

Comment: Sorry, home networking, consumer-grade hardware and host configurations/issues are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [su].

Comment: @Zac67 but I am not asking for trouble shooting. I am trying to understand how can this happen on a networking level.

Comment: We'd need to look into the device configurations which we won't for consumer-grade hardware because there's a thousand different vendors, each with their own configuration logic, poor documentation and an uncountable number of bugs out there.